# SSR with sveltekit not working getting error 500

Tags: server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I have this code for my `+page.ts` frontpage. I want the front page to be SSR, but im getting Server error 500 without the `export const ssr = false;`... But i want it to be ssr. What do i do wrong here?

i added `export const ssr = false;` to see if the code worked and it did. but than i dont have ssr

```js
import { getPosts } from '$lib/utils/sanity';
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';

export const load = (async () => {
    const posts = await getPosts();

    if (posts) {
        return {
            posts
        };
    }

    throw error(404, 'Not found');
}) satisfies PageLoad;
```

Comment: Show the exact errors you get. They should be found in the terminal running the dev server.